# Does a function in mysql only live as long as the connection?

Tags: mysql, function

If I create function in mysql, does it only live as long as the connection lasts? 
Which connection, the query connection or the DB connection?
Or does it get saved somewhere so you can call it anytime from any connection to that DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions, once created using the [CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html) construct, live in the DBMS until they are explicitly dropped, using the [`DROP FUNCTION <function name>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-function-udf.html). So, their life span is beyond the DB/query connection used for creating them.

Comment: Okay, that means I have to really make the function solid before saving it.
Yay for sqlfiddle ;-)
I'll accept your answer in 8 mins.

Comment: No, you can alter the function once created, using the ALTER FUNCTION construct in MySQL.

Comment: I figured so much, but that's a bother ;-) I'd rather spam sqlfiddle, is a lot faster than phpmyadmin ;-)